# Concatenating a string to an existing URL String - shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a string "http://localhost:8080/queue/item/259/" stored in the variable: queuedItemURL. I need to append string "api/json?pretty=true".

My script:

```
echo "================="
echo $queuedItemURL
queuedItemURL+="api/json?pretty=true"
echo $queuedItemURL
echo "============================="
```

The output I get is:

```
================= 
http://localhost:8080/queue/item/259/ 
api/json?pretty=true0/queue/item/259/
=============================
```

It seems there is some string replacement happening due to '/'.  Please help me in getting the string concatenated properly.

Comment: I think th problem id your $queuedItemURL variable that has a hidden \r; try `echo "=>$queuedItemURL<="`

Comment: <=http://localhost:8080/queue/item/271/

Comment: yes, this is the problem then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is your `$queuedItemURL` variable which has a hidden `\r`;

try:

```
queuedItemURL=$(echo $queuedItemURL | tr -d '\r')
```

before using it

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.  I started learning shell scripting only yesterday, so facing so many issues.

Comment: @Prasad Windows and Internet text documents generally use carriage return (`\r`) + linefeed (`\n`) at the end of lines; unix uses just linefeed, and will treat the carriage return as part of the line's content, and get confused (as you saw). You may need to do this sort of cleanup anytime you're getting data from a Windows or Internet source.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: after struggling for about 4 hours, I found this gem! Thank you!